# How to eliminate division inside code like "a/b>c/d"?

Tags: math, language-agnostic

For example, if I don't want division in "a/b==c/d",I can rewrite it as "a*d==b*c".

But "a/b>c/d" is not always = "a*d>b*c", for example:

a=20, b=5, c=9,d=3 : a/b>c/d is true and a*d>b*c is true

but

a=-20, b=-5, c=9,d=3 : a/b>c/d is true but a*d>b*c is false

I started to found the patten, it seems (I am not sure if it is right):

if b and d has same sign, a/b>c/d = a*d > b*c

if b and d has different sign, a/b > c/d = a*d < b*c

if I rewrite "a/b>c/d" as

```
(( (b>0 && d>0 || b<0 && d<0) && a*d>b*c) || ( ((b>0 && d<0) || b<0 && d>0) && a*d<b*c)
```

,it needs type more characters, also I need to type each variable more than 1 time,and this form is very hard to maintain if I want to change to

```
a/b>=c/d
```

or

```
a/b<c/d
```

Is there any method to eliminate division in a/b>c/d in simpler way?

Comment: Can you please clarify whether you are using floats or ints?

Comment: This question is *not* language agnostic!  Or at least, the answer depends on what types `a` and `b` are, whether `/` is doing a true division or some kind of truncated division (e.g., integer division, floor division), whether `/` is exact or not (e.g., floating-point result versus pure rational result), whether the base type is bounded (e.g., C's `int` versus Python's `int`), and so on.  It would be easier to answer if you have a particular target language in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite it as:

```
a*d*b*d > b*c*b*d
```

This way if b and d have different signs then b*d will be a negative number and the comparison will be flipped back the correct way. Be careful about overflows however. To make the code equivalent to a/b > c/d you will also need to check if b or d are zeros.

Answer (score 1):

When you multiply both sides of an inequality by some non-zero number `v`, then if `v` is negative you must reverse the direction of the inequality.

So in your case you are multiplying by `b*d` so

```
if (a/b > c/d) {
 ...
}
```

is equivalent to

```
v = b * d;
if(v==0) {
  error
}

if ( ( (v>0) && (a*d > c*b) ) || 
     ( (v<0) && (a*d < c*b) ) ) {
   ...
}
```

If you don't care whether you're using `>` or `>=`, or care about the handling of `v==0` you can rewrite this as

```
if ( (v>0) ^ (a*d > c*b ) ) {
  ...
}
```

There's further considerations required if `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are floating point numbers as you need to consider the behaviour of positive and negative infinity, signed zeros and "not a number" values.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can get the signs of b and d by bitwise operation, and then rewrite "a/b>c/d" as

```
(((b>>31)&1) ^ ((d>>31)&1)) ^ (ad > bc)
```

which is equivalent to

```
((b>0) ^ (d>0)) ^ (ad > bc)
```

say b and d are 32-bits integers